# RDS - 1205 lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

In Amazon-RDS I have table where insertion occurs automatically by python code, it works but sometimes the insertion stops and when i see the log it shows "lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction" its happening randomly. the size of my table 'Transaction' is 288 Mb. Is it happening because of the size or previous transaction is not completed? if so please help me out how to solve in rds..
Thanks.

Comment: Is this solved? I am running into the same issue and am looking for answers!

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the a timeout (as the error message suggests). Most likely it has nothing to do with transaction size; its the time to commit (or rollback) your transaction is what is getting in the way.

I'm assuming you're using MySql, is that right?

You might try to increase the timeout or review your process and understand if it should, actually, take that much of time to complete.

Comment: Yes I'm using rds mysql